# What does C# syntax ;; mean?

Tags: c#

My case:

```
// no syntax error
if (true) Console.Write("hi!");

// no syntax error
if (true) Console.Write("hi!"); ;

// no syntax error
if (true) Console.Write("hi!"); ; ;

// no syntax error
if (true) Console.Write("hi!"); ; ; ;
```

So, What does the second/third/fourth `;` mean? Should the compiler throw syntax error?

Comment: It means someone has copied the entire statement with the semicolon and forgot to remove the extra one. Technically it has no effect on the program whatsoever.

Comment: @user3185569 I was also thinking of giving a user-centric answer, but the user is only writing code (which may or may not follow valid syntax). The syntax itself is predefined ;)

Comment: @Badiparmagi a valid C# compiler is most definitely not interpreting code line by line. Imaging another statement behind double semicolons. I wouldn't want that to be skipped because of some next-line behavior.

Comment: @grek40 So,should we have a warning like: `empty statement in line...`?

Comment: @GREK40 thanks for explanation. deleted my comment.

Comment: An empty statement is highly unlikely to transform a correct program into an incorrect one. Hence, no need for a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`;` means empty statement. It does nothing.

In some cases (for example robotic programming), it is useful to instruct the program to continuously pool environment condition and do nothing until the condition fulfilled.

Example

```
// turn motor on so robot is going forward
TurnMotorOn();

// Do nothing (means motor is still on and robot is still going forward) until there is obstacle in front of the robot.
while(!ThereIsObstacle()) ;

// turn motor off so robot is stopped.
TurnMotorOff();
```

Comment: I just think about `while(!ThereIsObstacle()) ;` is same to `while(!ThereIsObstacle()) {}`. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The semicolon alone represents the  empty statement. So it will not give you any error. It will have no impact on your program.

The doc says;

> The empty statement consists of a single semicolon. It does nothing
>   and can be used in places where a statement is required but no action
>   needs to be performed.

Comment: But, if there is no block `{}`, we can only use 1 statement. Right? If right, there are many statements inside it.

Comment: You can use `;` without the `{}` as well although it would have no significance. Also there is no point of using multiple `;` as it will simply represent an empty statement.

Comment: @TânNguyễn only the first statement would belong to the `if`, so actually, in case of a following `else` there are errors to be expected (you didn't ask that though). See `if (true) Console.Write("hi!"); ; else Console.Write("I screwed up");`

Comment: Sorry, a small question? Why do we still need an `empty statement`? I mean, compiler doesn't complain about it. It takes nothing.

Comment: @TânNguyễn In conditional statements, the empty statement would be an alternative to the empty code block. Like `while (array[++count] == x) ;` as a way to increment `count` until some condition changes. So given one usage scenario, the question can be inverted: Why not?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ; it termed as the statement terminator as well as empty statement
```